# Handle leak in .Net threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This has actually bitten me a couple times. If you do simple code like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            Thread CE = new Thread(SendCEcho);
            CE.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            CE.IsBackground = true;
            CE.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    private void SendCEcho()
    {
        int Counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Counter++;
            Thread.Sleep(25);
        }
    }
```

Run this code and watch the handles fly! Thread.Sleep is so you can shut it down and it doesn't take over you computer. This should guarantee that the thread launched dies before the next thread is launched. Calling GC.Collect(); does nothing. From my observation this code loses 10 handles every refresh to the task manager at normal refresh.

It doesn't matter what is in the void SendCEcho() function, count to five if you want. When the thread dies there is one handle that does not get cleaned up.

With most programs this doesn't really matter because they do not run for extended periods of time. On some of the programs I've created they need to run for months and months on end.

If you exercise this code over and over, you can eventually leak handles to the point where the windows OS becomes unstable and it will not function. Reboot required.

I did solve the problem by using a thread pool and code like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadJobMoveStudy));
```

My question though is why is there such a leak in .Net, and why has it existed for so long? Since like 1.0? I could not find the answer here.

Comment: How you are viewing the handles?

Comment: @Yacoub In windows task manager. It seriously will leak all available handles and make the OS unstable.

Comment: @pm100 .net allows me to do this. There are plenty of tutorials showing to do threading like this. I promise if you run this code over and over, putting nothing in the void function, you will make the OS unstable.

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior you describe. Are you sure you're not doing something in SendCEcho that's leaking?

Comment: @pm100 Please explain. I do this code, no memory leak just one handle leak every time. Zombie? Join to the UI thread? It just works like that?

Comment: You are creating too many threads.

Comment: @Yacoub Then fine, set the sleep times to 300,000 and let it run for weeks like I have. No matter what if you create a thread with this code, and let it die, one handle is retained and not given back to the OS.

Comment: This should be reproducible with only a few threads. Can you call `GC.Collect()` after  each thread exists and see if the number of handles goes down?

Comment: You're creating threads that never ends. The loop in `SendCEcho` is endless.

Comment: @Brian Dude the loop goes to 5. It is not endless.

Comment: @Jake - I can see the handle count go up (yes, the loop terminates), but when the process end the thread handles are being returned to the OS.  Are you wondering why the thread handle is not returned to the OS when the thread terminates, but prior to process shutdown?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 5 + i++; )` ? Are you sure this is not a typo?

Comment: @Zach Yes a typo sorry I missed it. I corrected it.

Comment: @Clay Exactly. I tried a program that would exercise this code for honestly months on end, not start and stop the process, but let it run for months, and it kills the OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` after your call to GC.Collect();  I think that will get you what you are after.  Complete source below:

**EDIT**

Also take a look at this from 2005: https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/106014-net-1-1-possibly-1-0-also-threads-leaking-event-handles-bug. Almost the exact same code as yours.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            Thread CE = new Thread(SendCEcho);
            CE.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            CE.IsBackground = true;
            CE.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            CE = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }

    public static void SendCEcho()
    {
        int Counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            Counter++;
            Thread.Sleep(25);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I re-ran some tests and it appears you are correct. If I run this code I have no handle leaks with the added GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();. So then the question becomes why do I have to explicitly call this function or windows does not release the resources? I thought Garbage Collection happens automatically, at least eventually.  Apparently not, because without that call, it kills the OS eventually.

Comment: `Collect()` will run the collection, but the finalizable objects will be put onto the finalization queue. Their finalizers will only be run by the finalization thread at some point in the future. Calling `WaitForPendingFinalizers()` does what you would expect: blocks the current thread until the finalizer thread does its thing.

Comment: @dlev Such a simple answer, but perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're creating threads that never end. The for loop in `SendCEcho` never terminates, so the threads never end and thus cannot be reclaimed. If I fix your loop code then the threads finish and are reclaimed as expected. I'm unable to reproduce the problem with the code below.

```
static void SendCEcho()
{
    int Counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Counter++;
        Thread.Sleep(25);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your initial code read `for (int i = 0; i < 5 + i++)` - that will never terminate. Your corrected code doesn't compile. The point here is that it *does* matter what the thread method does.

Answer (score 5):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 + i++; )
```

Fairly bizarre typo, you have not re-created your real problem.  There is one, a Thread object consumes 5 operating system handles, its internal finalizer releases them.  A .NET class *normally* has a Dispose() method to ensure that such handles can be released early but Thread does not have one. That was courageous design, such a Dispose() method would be *very* hard to call.

So having to rely on the finalizer is a hard requirement.  In a program that has a "SendEcho" method, and does not do anything else, you are running the risk that the garbage collector never runs.  So the finalizer can't do its job.  It is then up to you to call GC.Collect() yourself.  You'd consider doing so every, say, 1000 threads you start.  Or use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() or Task.Run() so you recycle the threads, the logical approach.

Use Perfmon.exe to verify that the GC indeed doesn't run.  Add the .NET CLR Memory > # Gen 0 Collections counter for your program.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, but its just a for loop.